# How to make sidebar hidden in mobile view and toggle on click in mobile and other device view using vue.js and bootstrap4

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, vuejs2, sidebar, vuejs3

I have code that is working fine with pure bootstrap4 and javascript but when i tried to do with vuejs in mobile view sidebar is not showing below is the code that i want to change in vuejs but in vuejs it is showing toggleClass is not defined error

```
  $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
 });
```

[Here is the link for template that i am using.](https://startbootstrap.com/previews/simple-sidebar/)

Here is screenshot of the error

[image]
can anyone help me in this how to do and what is alternative to this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Mixing jQuery with Vue is not a good idea

Comment: ya that's why i  am asking how to do it in vuejs

Comment: methods:{
    togglemenu(){
      this.isActiveMenu = !this.isActiveMenu;
    }
  } i am using this but in mobile view it will cause sidebar will be open on load

Comment: Can't you do `data() {  return { isActiveMenu: false }}` when declaring it?

Comment: ya but i want sidebar to be active  for large devices like pc

Comment: Please show the full code for how you managed the sidebar for diferent devices with jQuery.  This should be done with CSS media queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution . Here is the answer

```js
import jquery from 'jquery';
mounted() {
      jquery("#menu-toggle").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        jquery("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
      });
}
```

This works for me